# Checking item location VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file with a pretty large list of items that are put on a certain location. What location the item has to be depends on a number of things. Color, shape, whether its wrapped or not, the size, the weight, etc.

So for instance a tv, thats blue, unwrapped, under 10 kilos goes into location 1.

But a tv, thats blue, unwrapped, over 10 kilos goes into location 5.

Now i know i could check the location with a (rather long) list of IF statements checking for every possible combination to see if the location is correct. The examples here are quite simple, but the real list gets quite large.

My question is (with my limited knowledge of excel/vba) if there would be a quicker way to do this?

The excel file im dealing with has the item in column A and all the other characteristics in the other columns.

**Problem: i have long list of items i have to assign to a location depending on (lets say) 5 variables. Doing this with IF statements would create a very long list of of statements. Is there a quicker way to do this?**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZFu-0YfBubQBUKQb3piqS3YJ2nSlKSTf4TktIsf-LuA/edit?usp=sharing

**Example file, note there are other colums in between the ones in the file but those are not relevant.**

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do it -- though, honestly, I don't know what it is since I have no idea what your problem actually is. You need to elaborate if you want some useful help. Include a clear problem statement, ideally with some examples of the code that you are currently trying to use.

Comment: Well, you can use some formula-magic in excel, with INDEX, MATCH and maybe OFFSET or INDIRECT functions. And helper tables. It will be painful, but it will be beautiful. And it will take a whole day to create if you are not an Excel wizard. Or you can go ahead and do the programming. Use indentation and divide your code into many subs to make it easier to follow. Maybe sometimes the `Select Case...End Select` structure will be easier on the eye than endless `If...ElseIf...End If` statements. Take a deep breath and start doing it!

Comment: You could create another table, that has all your variations. Then create a VBA find macro to search that table and get the output you want.

Comment: @Davesexcel that sounds like a good way to do this. Care to eleborate a little?

Comment: If column A was the products,column B,shapes,Column C weight, etc & the final column would be the location, You would be able to create a search macro to go through the variables and get the location.

Comment: Are you an elf? Is this for Santa?

Comment: Care to show a significant sample of the list, the variables and criteria... Would you share the workbook...

Comment: @EEM here is an example file with some explanation. Note that usually there are other colums in between the ones u see now. But they are not relevant for these checks. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZFu-0YfBubQBUKQb3piqS3YJ2nSlKSTf4TktIsf-LuA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> My question is (with my limited knowledge of excel/vba) if there would
> be a quicker way to do this?
>
> Problem: i have long list of items i
> have to assign to a location depending on (lets say) 5 variables.
> Doing this with IF statements would create a very long list of of
> statements. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Absolutely! The method\code below takes ~ 10 secs.

Let's first summarized the criteria to be applied:

[image]

As you can see the classification of the items depends on two variables rather than five.

The following code will assist you in applying the corresponding criteria.
As there may be `Country\Priority` combinations not defined in your criteria the default value assigned to `Location` is `!Err` to indicate the missing criteria.

***Note: Providing only the code required to apply the rules in line with the question, OP should be capable of producing all other necessary code.***

```
Sub Rng_Classify_Items()
Dim rTrg As Range   'Range to apply the rules
Dim sCtry As String, sPCod As String, sLoct As String
Dim bItmN As Byte, bCtry As Byte, bPCod As Byte, bLoct As Byte
Dim lRow As Long

    Rem Set Target Range
    'OP should be capable of producing this code
    '...    

    With rTrg

        Rem Set Field Positions
        On Error GoTo ExitTkn
        bItmN = Application.Match("Itemnumber", .Rows(1), 0)
        bCtry = Application.Match("Country", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPCod = Application.Match("Priority Code", .Rows(1), 0)
        bLoct = Application.Match("Location", .Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0

        For lRow = 2 To .Rows.Count

            Rem Validate Item Number
            If .Cells(lRow, bItmN).Value2 <> Empty Then
                        
                Rem Validate Rules
                sCtry = UCase(.Cells(lRow, bCtry).Value2)
                sPCod = UCase(.Cells(lRow, bPCod).Value2)
                sLoct = "!Err"  'Default Location applied to Country\Priority combinations not classified
                Select Case sCtry
                
                Case "414", "784"
                    If sPCod = "GREEN" Then sLoct = "Bicycling Holland"
                
                Case "CH"
                    sLoct = "Switzerland"
                    If sPCod = "GREEN" Then sLoct = "Bicycling Holland"
                
                Case "IE"
                    If sPCod = "GREEN" Then sLoct = "United Kingdom"
                    If sPCod = "RED" Then sLoct = "Europe"

                Case "GB"
                    If sPCod = "GREEN" Then sLoct = "United Kingdom"
                    If sPCod = "RED" Then sLoct = "TNT Uk"

                Case "AT", "BE", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GR", "IT", "LU", "NL", "PL", "SE", "SI", "SK"
                    If sPCod = "GREEN" Or sPCod = "RED" Then sLoct = "Europe"
                    
                End Select
                
                Rem Set Location
                .Cells(lRow, bLoct).Value = sLoct

    End If: Next: End With

ExitTkn:

End Sub
```

Suggest to visit these pages:

[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), [WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx),  [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)

[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx), [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx)

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Worksheet Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx),

Do let me know of any question regarding the code provided to answer your question...

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes i simplified the example, but this is more then enough to know how to do the rest myself. Thank again!

Comment: If this solves the issue please acknowledge the answer and help us to keep the site updated. Thanks....

Comment: havent had the chance to actually test it yet. Will do tonight.

Comment: I have been able to get it working thanks to your code. I do require some explanation to understand it though.

When i was using IF statements to do things, i would use a loop with a cell offset to check for instance the priority code. 

You seem to do that with the part under the Field positions and Validate rules.

How does this work? Why are they (the bCtry etc) set as Byte? Is this exclusive to Case select?

Comment: The code goes row by row and get the value of country and priority using the position of the field `Validate Rules`; then it uses the `Select Case` to perform the comparisons (similar to IF's, but way more flexible). Please read the suggested pages to grab a deeper understanding, also [Data Type Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would build a table of all unique options and locations something like this

```
BlueWrapped10K+,1
BlueWrapped7K+,2
BlueWrapped5K+,3
BlueWrapped0K+,4
BlueUnwrapped10K+,5
...
etc.
```

and then concatenate the item's values, like

```
=A2&B2&INDEX({"10K+","7K+","5K+","0K+"},MATCH(C2,{999,9.99,6.99,4.99},-1))
```

Obviously, with variable values such as the weight you would need to take care to construct your identification formula, but once done it could then be used in a VLOOKUP against that table like so

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&INDEX({"10K+","7K+","5K+","0K+"},MATCH(C2,{999,9.99,6.99,4.99},-1)),MyLookup,2,FALSE)
```